# Como separar emails por ponto e vírgula no SQL Server?

Tags: sql

tenho uma coluna que possui vários emails separados por ponto e vírgula, gostaria de saber como separar esses e-mails e inserir separadamente em outra tabela. Na imagem abaixo está mais detalhado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta quebrar os email usando `STRING_SPLIT` e posteriormente um insert com o resultado do `SELECT`, assim:

```
INSERT INTO EMAILS(emails)
SELECT A.value AS EMAIL_QUEBRADO
FROM EMAIL X
OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(X.email, ',') AS A
```

Comment: Obrigado, testei aqui e deu certo ;)